# Python ModelSerializer change name to start with "@" sign

Tags: python, serialization, json-ld

Python Model

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    context = models.CharField()
```

Serializer

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ("context")
```

View

```
class FooListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Foo.objests.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
```

My structure is like above. And it produces the following Json as expected.

```
{
    "context": "http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld"
}
```

Is it possible to add "@" sign at the beginning of the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your serializer with below code:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ("context", )

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(FooSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data["@context"] = instance.context
        del data["context"]
        return data
```

:)

Comment: I was tryin to accomplish it with code below but it wasn't working. Your solution worked. Thanks..



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["context"].label = "@context"